# Putting Na on several columns according to conditions on certain columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with amount of bills columns,with dates and ids associated with those amounts. I would like to set the columns to Na when the date is less than 2016-12-31 and their associated id and amount. Here is an example

| ID customer | Bill1 | Date 1 | ID Bill 1 | Bill2 | Date 2 | ID Bill 2 | Bill3 | Date3 | ID Bill 3 | Gender | Age |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 6 | 2000-10-04 | 1 | 45 | 2000-11-05 | 2 | 51 | 1999-12-05 | 8 | M | 25 |
| 6 | 8 | 2016-05-03 | 7 | 39 | 2017-08-09 | 8 | 38 | 2018-07-14 | 17 | W | 54 |
| 12 | 14 | 2016-11-16 | 10 | 73 | 2017-05-04 | 15 | 14 | 2017-07-04 | 35 | M | 68 |

And I would like to get this:

| ID customer | Bill1 | Date 1 | ID Bill 1 | Bill2 | Date 2 | ID Bill 2 | Bill3 | Date 3 | ID Bill 3 | Gender | Age |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | Nan | Nan | Nan | Nan | Nan | Nan | Nan | Nan | Nan | M | 25 |
| 6 | Nan | Nan | Nan | 39 | 2017-08-09 | 8 | 38 | 2018-07-14 | 17 | W | 54 |
| 12 | Nan | Nan | Nan | 73 | 2017-05-04 | 15 | 14 | 2017-07-04 | 35 | M | 68 |

Answer (score 1):

One option is to create a [`MultiIndex.from_frame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_frame.html#pandas-multiindex-from-frame) based on the values extracted [`str.extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html#pandas-series-str-extractall):

```
new_df = df.set_index(['ID customer', 'Gender', 'Age'])
orig_cols = new_df.columns  # Save For Later
new_df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(
    new_df.columns.str.extractall(r'(.*?)(?:\s+)?(\d+)')
)
```

```
0                      Bill       Date ID Bill Bill       Date ID Bill Bill       Date ID Bill
1                         1          1       1    2          2       2    3          3       3
ID customer Gender Age                                                                        
4           M      25     6 2000-10-04       1   45 2000-11-05       2   51 1999-12-05       8
6           W      54     8 2016-05-03       7   39 2017-08-09       8   38 2018-07-14      17
12          M      68    14 2016-11-16      10   73 2017-05-04      15   14 2017-07-04      35
```

Then [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html#pandas-dataframe-mask) on the `Date` column (in level 0) where dates are less than the threshold:

```
new_df = new_df.mask(new_df['Date'].lt(pd.to_datetime('2016-12-31')))
```

```
0                      Bill Date ID Bill  Bill       Date ID Bill  Bill       Date ID Bill
1                         1    1       1     2          2       2     3          3       3
ID customer Gender Age                                                                    
4           M      25   NaN  NaT     NaN   NaN        NaT     NaN   NaN        NaT     NaN
6           W      54   NaN  NaT     NaN  39.0 2017-08-09     8.0  38.0 2018-07-14    17.0
12          M      68   NaN  NaT     NaN  73.0 2017-05-04    15.0  14.0 2017-07-04    35.0
```

Lastly, restore columns and order:

```
new_df.columns = orig_cols  # Restore from "save"
new_df = new_df.reset_index().reindex(columns=df.columns)
```

```
   ID customer  Bill1 Date 1  ID Bill 1  Bill2     Date 2  ID Bill 2  Bill3      Date3  ID Bill 3 Gender  Age
0            4    NaN    NaT        NaN    NaN        NaT        NaN    NaN        NaT        NaN      M   25
1            6    NaN    NaT        NaN   39.0 2017-08-09        8.0   38.0 2018-07-14       17.0      W   54
2           12    NaN    NaT        NaN   73.0 2017-05-04       15.0   14.0 2017-07-04       35.0      M   68
```

---

All Together:

(ensure Date Columns are DateTime)

```
df['Date 1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date 1'])
df['Date 2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date 2'])
df['Date3'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date3'])
```

```
new_df = df.set_index(['ID customer', 'Gender', 'Age'])
orig_cols = new_df.columns  # Save For Later
new_df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(
    new_df.columns.str.extractall(r'(.*?)(?:\s+)?(\d+)')
)
new_df = new_df.mask(new_df['Date'].lt(pd.to_datetime('2016-12-31')))
new_df.columns = orig_cols  # Restore from "save"
new_df = new_df.reset_index().reindex(columns=df.columns)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
#Assumption Your dates are of dtype datetime[ns]   
c=~df.filter(like='Date').lt(pd.to_datetime('2016-12-31'))
c=pd.DataFrame(c.values.repeat(3,1),columns=df.columns[1:10])
```

Finally:

```
out=df[df.columns[1:10]]
out=out[c].join(df[['ID customer','Gender','Age']])
```

Now If you print `out` you will get your desired output